# ClassNotFoundException in AKS Pod: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ProxyBuilderImpl - Error Occurs in UAT Env, but Not in Test Env

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, azure-aks

I am encountering a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` specifically for the class `org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ProxyBuilderImpl` when my service attempts to connect to the Keycloak server using the Keycloak admin client.

Here are the specifics of the issue:

- The error occurs in the User Acceptance Testing (UAT) environment running in an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster.
- The service is Dockerized, and the Docker image is built and deployed in the test environment, which operates on a different AKS cluster than the UAT environment.
- The Docker image is then copied from the test environment and deployed in the UAT environment.
- Importantly, the `ClassNotFoundException` does not occur in the test environment.

I have checked the following aspects:

- Dependencies: The required dependencies, including the Resteasy library, are included in the Docker image.
- Environment Variables: I have verified that all necessary environment variables are correctly set in the UAT environment.
- Configuration: There are no apparent differences in configurations between the test and UAT environments.
- Classpath: The classpath seems to be correctly configured in the Docker image.

I have reviewed the error logs, but they primarily indicate the `ClassNotFoundException` without providing additional insights into the root cause.

Any guidance or insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. If you need more details or logs, please let me know. Thank you!

Below is the errorl log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while adding Patients to batch 
    at com.xxx.workxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service.impl.CxxxxxxxxServiceImpl.savePatients(CxxxxxxxxServiceImpl.java:235)
    at com.xxx.workxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service.impl.ExxxxServiceImpl.saveEvents(ExxxxServiceImpl.java:120)
    at com.xxx.workxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service.impl.ExxxxServiceImpl.segregateEventsByEntitiesAndSave(ExxxxServiceImpl.java:184)
    at com.xxx.workxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service.impl.ExxxxServiceImpl.lambda$saveEventsAsEntities$0(ExxxxServiceImpl.java:97)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1804)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1796)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ProxyBuilderImpl
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ProxyBuilder.builder(ProxyBuilder.java:41)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientWebTarget.createProxyBuilder(ClientWebTarget.java:107)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientWebTarget.proxy(ClientWebTarget.java:94)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.spi.ResteasyClientClassicProvider.targetProxy(ResteasyClientClassicProvider.java:48)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.token.TokenManager.<init>(TokenManager.java:61)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak.<init>(Keycloak.java:91)
    at org.keycloak.admin.client.KeycloakBuilder.build(KeycloakBuilder.java:152)
    at com.xxx.workxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.config.KeycloakConfig.getInstance(KeycloakConfig.java:37)
    at com.xxx.workxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service.impl.KxxxxxxxServiceImpl.getInstance(KxxxxxxxServiceImpl.java:240)
    at com.xxx.workxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service.impl.KxxxxxxxServiceImpl.getRealmResource(KxxxxxxxServiceImpl.java:226)
    at com.xxx.workxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service.impl.KxxxxxxxServiceImpl.importUsers(KxxxxxxxServiceImpl.java:132)
    at com.xxx.workxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.service.impl.CxxxxxxxxServiceImpl.savePatients(CxxxxxxxxServiceImpl.java:227)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ProxyBuilderImpl
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.ProxyBuilder.builder(ProxyBuilder.java:35)
    ... 21 more
```

I tried to reproduce the error in my local system by pulling the image, running in it, and executed the follwoing commands to check if the docker container has the class

```
docker exec -it <docker_id> /bin/bash
jar -tf /root/.m2/repository/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-client/4.7.9.Final/resteasy-client-4.7.9.Final.jar | grep ProxyBuilderImpl.class
```

It gave the following
org/jboss/resteasy/client/jaxrs/internal/proxy/ProxyBuilderImpl.class

Comment: The ClassNotFoundException for org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ProxyBuilderImpl indicates that the required class is not found at runtime. Since you've confirmed that the JAR containing this class is present in the Docker image, Check the version of the Resteasy library in the UAT environment. It is possible that the version in the UAT environment is different from the version in the test environment, which could cause the missing class error. Make sure that the Resteasy library version is the same in both environments. classloading issues can arise due to conflict in hierarchy.

Comment: Both UAT and Test environments have same versions of resteasy-client library.

Comment: The hints of @user1213843 helped. We replaced our asynchronous future with a synchronous call and it's working. So it seems to be a concurrency issue, not sure what exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same type of issue today. I'm using the keycloak-admin-client to configure multiple realms, and I was doing this through the Stream API, specifically the sequential stream, Collection.stream(). I'm using spring-boot with embedded tomcat.

I started testing the use of parallel stream through Collection.parallelStream(), and for some of the items I get basically the same stacktrace as you do, with cause: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ProxyBuilderImpl

I noticed a pattern for the items that failed, and that was that the underlying Thread was based on the ForkJoinPool. It seems to me like the classpath for these threads do not include certain classes. I wont speculate on why that is. Someone more qualified could probably supply information on that.

I "fixed" my issue by setting up a java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService instead (java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int)). Then I loop through my realm collection and submit my tasks through ExecutorService.invokeAll (I need to block until all are done). After doing this I have not been able to reproduce the issue.

As to why you get different results based on the environment you run your code in, is it due to varying number of items in your Collection? Ref "Exception while adding Patients to batch"